# what are the differences between receptive field (RF) and field-of-views (FOV) in DeepLab papers?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, convolution

I am learning the deeplab models. However, some concepts in the papers made me confused. Receptive field (RF) and field-of-views (FOV) are two concepts mentioned in the Deeplabv1 paper. I know that receptive field is defined as the region in the input space that a particular CNN’s feature is looking at. What about the field-of-views (FOV)? Are they the same?

Answer (score 6):

It means the same thing. I guess the authors are specifically referring to effect of using "atrous" or "dilated" convolutions here, as far as I can tell FOV is the same as receptive field.